# web2py with MongoHQ deploy at openshift: RuntimeError: no driver available ('pymongo',)

Tags: openshift, web2py, mongohq

I'm trying to deploy my app to openshift, but I got error message. Following are my logs:

```
==> app-root/logs/web2py.log <==
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 18:08:10, GET, /admin/static/images/questions.png, HTTP/1.1, 304, 0.010710
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 18:11:12, HEAD, /, HTTP/1.1, 303, 0.000809
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 18:11:13, HEAD, /, HTTP/1.1, 303, 0.004810
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 18:41:05, GET, /MarkIt/, HTTP/1.1, 500, 5.459672
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 18:49:36, GET, /MarkIt/, HTTP/1.1, 500, 5.658112
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 18:54:00, GET, /MarkIt/, HTTP/1.1, 500, 5.682422
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 19:10:50, HEAD, /, HTTP/1.1, 303, 0.000960
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 19:10:50, HEAD, /, HTTP/1.1, 303, 0.001024
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 19:56:22, GET, /MarkIt/, HTTP/1.1, 500, 5.487744
127.5.151.1, 2014-06-01 20:04:03, GET, /MarkIt/, HTTP/1.1, 500, 5.431559

==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error] DEBUG: connect attempt 4, connection error:
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error]   File "/var/lib/openshift/538b85575973cad5cc000794/app-root/runtime/repo/libs/gluon/dal.py", line 7409, in __init__
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error]     self._adapter = ADAPTERS[self._dbname](**kwargs)
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error]   File "/var/lib/openshift/538b85575973cad5cc000794/app-root/runtime/repo/libs/gluon/dal.py", line 5240, in __init__
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error]     if do_connect: self.find_driver(adapter_args)
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error]   File "/var/lib/openshift/538b85575973cad5cc000794/app-root/runtime/repo/libs/gluon/dal.py", line 746, in find_driver
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error]     raise RuntimeError("no driver available %s" % str(self.drivers))
[Sun Jun 01 20:04:02 2014] [error] RuntimeError: no driver available ('pymongo',)
97.77.53.27 - - [01/Jun/2014:20:03:56 -0400] "GET /MarkIt/ HTTP/1.1" 500 843 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/537.75.14"
```

I'm using MongoHQ, the app runs totally fine if I run it locally.

The way I connect to MongoHQ is in db.py:

```
if not request.env.web2py_runtime_gae:
    ## if NOT running on Google App Engine use SQLite or other DB
    #db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',pool_size=1,check_reserved=['all'])
    db = DAL("mongodb://username:password@oceanic.mongohq.com:10017/MarkIt",
    check_reserved=["mongodb_nonreserved",],  adapter_args={"safe":False})
```

Only one of my applications in web2py uses MongoHQ and that's the one I could not open. Other work fine.

I think it might be dependency issue but I don't know how to resolve it.

I also did `rhc cartridge add mongodb-2.4 -a my app` but it does not help.

Comment: Most certainly dependencies. What content is in your setup.py?

Comment: It should be in the root folder of your project. If you do not have one then that is essentially your problem. Try some reading here on [installing with openshift](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1017-adding-dependencies-to-applications) and general documentation on [python setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html)

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you so much! I just found the setup.py and add the pymongo and everything works!!